# Extract first word using regex in grep

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

I have a large text file containing patterns such as

```
*pattern1, 34:38,info=a1,signal=s1
*pattern2, 32:38,info=a1,signal=s1
*pattern2,36:38,info=a1,signal=s1
*pattern_4,38:38,info=a1,signal=s1
```

I want to extract the unique first words before first comma using `grep`. I tried using `grep '^*[A-Za-z]' file.txt | sort --uniq` and `grep '^*[^,]' file.txt | sort --uniq` but not getting the first word only.  Can anyone comment?

Comment: Can you use awk: `awk -F"," '{print $1}' file.txt` ?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the words are comma separated, just search for anything but comma from the start of  each line.

Use the `-o` to only print the matching part of each line. `grep` is usually used for filtering, not for extraction, but this option can be used sometimes.

```sh
grep -o '^[^,]*' file.txt | sort -u
```

Answer (score 3):

To get first word and making it unique, you may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, '!uniq[$1]++ {print $1}' file

*pattern1
*pattern2
*pattern_4
```

Condition `!uniq[$1]++` will return true only when `$1` is not found in array `uniq`. Once we add an element in this array we increment it's value to `1` thus causing `!uniq[$1]++` to return false.

`{print $1}` will be executed only for `true` case.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and with GNU `awk` using `gensub` you could try following. This will provide unique values in 1st column in whole Input_file.

```
awk '!seen[$0=gensub(/,.*/,"\\1","1")]++' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `gensub` we are getting everything before first comma and then in array we are negating duplicate occurrences in each line as per requirement.

Comment: Could be less effective on huge files(compare to anubhava's solution; not tested though), but is handy as an alternative for normal usage.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using `grep '^*[A-Za-z]' file.txt | sort --uniq`

grep by default shows the entire line that it matches.  If you want grep to show only what was matched, use the `-o` option.

```
grep '^[^,]*' -o file.txt | sort -u
```

The `[^,]` means "anything that isn't a comma.